# How to handle the case when FirebaseAuth sign in fails due to network being offline?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement sign in authentication with `FirebaseAuth` using `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` for my Android app. How can I handle the case when Internet connection is offline so that I can generate a `Toast message` regarding network issue.

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling around a bit, I found out that that it can be handled using `OnFailureListener` as `Exception` generated by `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` is an instance of `FirebaseNetworkException`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, I create a class... and then use the following code.

```
 public class InternetStatus {

    private static InternetStatus instance = new InternetStatus();
    static Context context;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    NetworkInfo wifiInfo, mobileInfo;
    boolean connected = false;

    public static InternetStatus getInstance(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx.getApplicationContext();
        return instance;
    }

    public boolean isOnline() {
        try {
            connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            connected = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() &&
                    networkInfo.isConnected();
            return connected;


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("CheckConnectivity Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            Log.v("connectivity", e.toString());
        }
        return connected;
    }


}
```

And then in order to use it...

```
if (InternetStatus.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).isOnline()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "User is online");
        // proceed with your firebase auth code.
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "User does not have an internet connection");
        //create a toast message, or however you want to handle this error.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet:

```
public static boolean hasActiveInternetConnection(Context context) {
    if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
            urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500); 
            urlc.connect();
            return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error checking internet connection", e);
        }
    } else {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "No network available!");
    }
    return false;
}
```

and also add this in your Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```